# How to improve security with psycopg2 connection?

Tags: python, postgresql, security, psycopg2

I have a PostgreSQL database and I have a script that uses data in the db to update a website. In the script I have the following code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=name user=user password=password')
```

Is there a better or more secure way to connect to the db without exposing my password in the script?

I have the same issue in Django with the settings.py file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store your postgresql credentials and dont hard code them in .py scripts. To do this, I suggest you to use `django-decouple` module. 
With this module, You can store your database credentials in a `.env` file like this

```
DB_NAME=DB_NAME
DB_USER=DB_USER
DB_PASSWORD=DB_PASS
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

and then you can use it in your python or django project as simple as drinking a cup of tea :)

**Related links :** 
djang-decouple official page 
https://pypi.org/project/django-decouple/ 
nice and simple tutorial to learn how to use django-decouple 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

AWS and Databricks have secret management tools letting you to store your password as a secret.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to store your key chain in a permission-controlled directory, and make your script read that credential file to extract username and password. This way you could mask the credential from whom could view the script but have no permission to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a variable, store it in a module/package, them in your script write :

```
from *libname* import sqlpassword

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=name user=user password=sqlpassword')
```