# How to use encrypted password with Postgres and psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, docker, encryption, psycopg2

I have a Docker container which used for a Flask application and I have defined the password in the environment variable like the following

```
ENV DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Now in this scenario, I need to put the password in the file and this file is part of the version control. I need to hide the password in such a way that the other people including the DevOps will not be able to get the password. I can do encryption and decryption, but then also, the code is visible and other developers can print the password. I am using `psycopg2` to connect to the database and has the following code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=os.environ['DATABASE_HOST'],
            database=os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'],
            user=os.environ['DATABASE_USER'],
            password=os.environ['DATABASE_PASSWORD']
        )
```

I am looking for a way that I can hide the password from the outside. I am not sure this is even possible. Or is there any other way that I can store the passwords and use them in the code? Any service I can use for this purpose? Please suggest.

Comment: Usually you keep environment variables _outside_ of version control - see for example the 12 factor app website.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335694/1547595), I suggest you storing your usernames and passwords in a `settings.ini` file and reading them with [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/).